# Displaying result of addition in a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple code that add two numbers. The result is displayed in a textbox. How can I display the result in a div, rather than a textbox?

Here is my current code, which displays the result in a textbox.

```
function sum() {
var field1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value; 
var field2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value; 
var field1V = parseInt(field1);
var field2V = parseInt(field2);
var result = field1V + field2V;  
if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
     }
}

<input type="text" placeholder="Type number" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Type number" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum();" />
Result: <input type="text" id="txt3" readonly />
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function sum() {
  var field1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value; 
  var field2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value; 
  var field1V = parseInt(field1);
  var field2V = parseInt(field2);
  var result = field1V + field2V;  
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Type number" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Type number" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum();" />
Result: <input type="text" id="txt3" readonly />
Result: <div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly.